# Bulk import of url to parse with WP RSS aggregator wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am using **WP RSS aggregator** plugin to parse feed URLs.

Now I am having more than 1000 links to parse with category specification. How can I parse this url in bulk? Currently I am doing this by manual data(URL) enty.

Looking forward for relevant answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "msds_pif_cat"; // represents the name of the product category            as shown in the URL
 return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

use this function